# Finiteness of torsion in $\mathcal{K}_2$-cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, algebraic-k-theory

Let $F$ be a number field, $C$ be a smooth projective curve over $F$ and $\mathfrak{C}$ be a proper regular model. I am interested in $\mathcal{K}_2$-cohomology, i.e., Zariski cohomology of the sheaf of second K-groups, on $\mathfrak{C}$ which can be computed via the Gersten complex
$$
K_2(F(C))\to\bigoplus_{x\in\mathfrak{C}^{(1)}}\kappa(x)^\times\to\bigoplus_{y\in\mathfrak{C}^{(2)}}\mathbb{Z}.
$$

> Is it known if the torsion in $H^1(\mathfrak{C},\mathcal{K}_2)$, i.e., the middle cohomology of the above complex, is finite?

Of course, this is a consequence of standard finiteness conjectures, but I am interested if it can be proved *unconditionally*. If this is not known unconditionally, is it possible to say where the difficulty lies?

Related results I know:

- Via etale cohomology computations the $p$-torsion is finite for each prime $p$, but I couldn't find a global finiteness result.
- $H^0(\mathfrak{C},\mathcal{K}_2)$ has finite torsion by a result of Colliot-Thélène and Raskind, $H^2(\mathfrak{C},\mathcal{K}_2)$ is finite by a result of Bloch.
- $H^1(\mathfrak{X},\mathcal{K}_2)$ is finite in the function field case, i.e., if $\mathfrak{X}$ is a  surface over a finite field. This can be found in papers of Raskind or Kato.

**Bonus question:** This is closely related to the question if the torsion in $K_2(\mathcal{O}_F)$ is finite if $F$ is a number field. This is true, due to Bass and Tate. 
But is there a different argument for this finiteness of torsion? For instance, is it possible to prove finiteness of 
$$
\ker\left(H^1_{et}(F,\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}(2))\to \bigoplus_{\mathfrak{p}}H^0_{et}(\kappa(\mathfrak{p}),\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}(1))\right)
$$ 
without going through finiteness results in K-theory?